# Find values from JSON string on the basis of dropdown selection values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON string in a session. If I pass the index 1000 in the array then I get a value, but when passing a dynamic value coming from the previous page then I get the error:

> Undefined index: [6000 ] in D:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\ajaxItemSelect.php on line 23

My code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $jsonString = isset($_SESSION['jsonString']) ? $_SESSION['jsonString'] : '';
    if (isset($_REQUEST['selectedvalues'])){
        $selectedvalues = isset($_POST['selectedvalues']) ? $_POST['selectedvalues'] : '';
?>

<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">

    <?php echo $jsonString['m_materialSupportedList'][1000]['itemName']['en'];

    echo $jsonString['m_materialSupportedList'][$selectedval]['itemFieldOneLabel']['en']; ?>
</label>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: Check the index exists before you access it.

Comment: Where in your code does `$selectedval` get set? Is that supposed to be `$selectedvalues`??